# RNLocation Package issue : subscribeToLocationUpdates sometimes never fires and sometimes it automatically starts working

Tags: javascript, react-native, package.json

**getLatestLocation() returns null and subscribeToLocationUpdates never fires :**

`import RNLocation from 'react-native-location';`

```
RNLocation.requestPermission({
  ios: 'whenInUse',
  android: {detail: 'coarse'},
}).then((granted) => {
  if (granted) {
    RNLocation.getLatestLocation().then((loc) => {
      Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(loc)); // <--- this returns null
    });
    RNLocation.subscribeToLocationUpdates((locations) => { // <-- this never fires
      const {latitude, longitude} = locations[0];
      Alert.alert(`${JSON.stringify({latitude, longitude})}`);
    });
  }
});`
```

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this issue by changing the detail value for android:
from **coarse** to **fine**. Now it is working as expected.

`android: {detail: 'fine'},`

Hope this solve your issue